# Cannot use FireDAC with RAD studio 10.2 release 1

Tags: delphi, rad, firedac

I've updated RAD Studio 10.2 to the recent 10.2.1 release. 
Now, when I compile a previously working program, I get this error :

> [dcc32 Fatal Error] TestForm.pas(7): F2051 Unit FireDAC.Stan.Error was compiled with a different version of FireDAC.Stan.ResStrs.S_FD_PgUnsupTextType.

It's easy to reproduce on an empty project : I simply insert a `TFDPhysMySQLDriverLink` or `TFDMSSQLDriverLink` FireDAC component on a form and I get the same error.

Could you help me ?

**--- Edited ---**

I've kept RAD 10.1 Berlin installed but it seems that paths are completely separated between both installs (18.0 versus 19.0 directories).
I've installed RAD 10.2.1 yesterday and I've not changed any system path. It was working perfectly with RAD 10.2...

The compiler path of the Test project (see above) is empty.

Here are the "Tools/Options/Delphi Options/Library/Library" paths :

```
$(BDSLIB)\$(Platform)\release
$(BDSUSERDIR)\Imports
$(BDS)\Imports
$(BDSCOMMONDIR)\Dcp
$(BDS)\include
```

Here are the related delphi environment variables :

```
$(BDSLIB) == h:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0\lib
$(BDSUSERDIR) == H:---CCF\Users\CC\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0
$(BDS) == h:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\19.0
$(BDSCOMMONDIR) == C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0
```

These paths are correct except H:---CCF\Users\CC\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0 which doesn't exist.

$(BDSLIB) leads to the correct versions of FireDAC.Stan.ResStrs.dcu (dated on 29/07/2017).

I've tried to displace "h:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\18.0" directory but the problem is still the same.

When I include the H:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\source\data\firedac in my project search path, this solves the issue but the FireDAC DCUs come into my project and this is not a normal situation.

Comment: Submit a bug report

Comment: Search your h/disk and check that you have only one instance of the DCUs of these two Pas files.

Comment: @David - I've just posted a bug report at Embarcadero. Thank you

Comment: @MartynA - I'm sure that other instances of this DCU exist because RAD 10.1 is still installed. I've temporarily displaced the directory containing 10.1 files ("18.0" directory) without success. I've also checked that the internal environment variables like $BDSLIB are containing valid paths.

Comment: Well, IME one can always avoid this error if the sources of both units (and those they depend on) are available.  Probably, the compiler isn't finding the correct version of  S_FD_PgUnsupTextType.Dcu.  Include the source path to your FDac sources as the first path in your project, then place a "compile stopper" like an explanation mark at the top of S_FD_PgUnsupTextType.Pas.  If your project compiles without complaint, there's your answer.

Comment: Works here - must be something with your system.

Comment: @MartynA - I've edited my question because it was too long in a comment (see above). In brief, when I include the FireDAC source directory in my project search path, this solves the issue. But the FireDAC DCUs come into my project and I don't understand why the specified system paths are not used by the RAD... In addition, I've displaced the 18.0 (RAD 10.1) directory and the problem is  the same.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe - I've edited my question above with more details.